# Using Python find a string and delete all lines from the matched string to the end of the file

Tags: python

My Google skills may be lacking, but I'm surprised that I've not been able to find anything that exactly matches what I am trying to do here in Python (it has to be in Python).

I have a lot of plain text files (600+), some of these files contain a section I want to delete. The section *always* starts with a line containing a Markdown header: `###### Backlinks`. I'm trying to find the first line of that section, delete it, and then also delete all the lines after it, all the way until the end of the file.

A few points to clarify:

- The section I want to delete *always* starts with the specific string: `###### Backlinks`.
- It is *always* the last section of the file.
- I *always* want to delete from the start of the backlinks section to the end of the file.

The plain text files *always* follow the below structure, but vary in size and length:

```
---
note: 20200806151434
title: Vestibulum Ante
---

# Vestibulum ante

Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Suspendisse ultrices erat eu magna aliquet, vitae commodo felis porttitor.

###### Backlinks

- [[20200806151410]]
- [[20200806151414]]
```

I'm no expert with Python, and because I've not really found anything that really matches what I'm after, I'm not sure where to start. I thought it would be simpler than it currently seems to be.

I'm using the following code so far, and I am able to find the `###### Backlinks` string where it exists in each file I'm looping through. At the moment, I'm just printing the string, and the path to the file that contains the string, but as above I actually want to delete the `###### Backlinks` line and all lines after it silently and safely (without running the risk of losing the content of any of the files).

Please let me know if you need me to clarify. Any help or pointers will be much appreciated.

```py
path_notes = /home/user/notes

for note in path_notes:
    with open(note, "r") as note_content:
    
        # Find existing backlinks and get line number:
        for line in note_content:
            if line.__contains__("###### Backlinks"):
                print(line.strip("\n") + " " + note)
```

Comment: Just a side note: you're not supposed to use `__contains__` directly like that. Just use `if "###### Backlinks" in line:` instead. `in` defers to `__contains__`.

Comment: You will _very rarely_ find code online that does _exactly_ what you're looking for it to do. As a programmer, figuring out the algorithm to obtain the results you want _is your job_. Converting that to code is fairly trivial compared to figuring out the logic. The algorithm you're looking for here seems to be: 1. Read file line 2. Does the line contain a search string? 3.1. If no, write the line somewhere else (to stdout / another file?) and move on 3.2. If yes, stop processing the file. The code you have shared does 1 and 2. Now you need to make it do 3.1 and 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to remove the portion of the file that comes after `"###### Backlinks"` would be to loop through all lines and write them to the same file, just breaking the loop as soon as `"###### Backlinks"` appears.

```
fname = "somefile.txt"
t = open(fname,"r")
lines = t.readlines()
t.close()

t = open(fname,"w") ## Caution! This overwrites the original file. Be sure to try this in a safe place.
i = 0
while i < len(lines) and not "##### Backlinks" in lines[i]:
    t.write(lines[i])
    i+=1
t.close()
```

This overwrites your file with all lines in the original file except anything that comes after "##### Backlinks" is encountered.